# C2248: Cannot access private member declared in class - only occurs in .h file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gdi+

I'm trying to store objects in member variables instead of creating them and destroying them every time I need them. In my particular case, the creation and destruction of my objects are expensive.

This is how I initialize a Pen in a .cpp file

```
void Foo::func()
{
    Pen pen(Color(255, 0, 0, 0), 1);
}
```

I want to store a pen in a member variable instead, so I try this. The compiler thinks I'm trying to declare a function, so it does not work.

```
class Foo
{
private:
    Gdiplus::Pen pen(Gdiplus::Color(255, 0, 0, 0), 1);
}
```

To get around this, I try using another constructor. This gives me the 2248 error.

```
class Foo
{
private:
    Gdiplus::Pen pen = Gdiplus::Pen(Gdiplus::Color(1, 1, 1, 1));
};
```

Is there another way to go about this so I can store these objects in member variables?

Comment: Use the constructor to initialize member variables, or [C++11 syntax](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization).  You should in general prefer only creating GDI+ objects inside the code that uses them, storage is limited and creation is very cheap.

Comment: I timed out the performance with std::clock, and creating just a few pens and brushes costed me about 6ms. That was far too long if I wanted to achieve a high framerate.

Comment: It takes less than a microsecond.  clock() does not have sufficient resolution to measure that, use QueryPerformanceCounter() instead.